# Pre-made Local notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios7, calendar, uilocalnotification, reminders

I'm trying to create a sort of pre-made reminder app, where the user can select a "plan" to receive notifications daily. Depending on the plan, there would be a different list of pre-made reminders that would need to be checked off each day. Also, there should be only one notification for the whole list of reminders. Ideally there would be a calendar view as well, but seeing as I'm already nearly in over my head, that should probably wait. I'm assuming I'm going to have to get friendly with UILocalNotification, but I can't find a tutorial that I can edit to fit my needs (as I've done in the past.)

I've been working with [AppCoda's](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial) tutorial, but I just can't see how I'm going to make this work.

I'm (almost) a complete beginner working with Xcode, so extremely specific answers and tutorial links would be most appreciated!

-

*Edit: I can figure out how to let a user set the time and date of a notification, but I want to have a pre-made notification. So when a user selects plan one, a notification would be set for every week day at 1pm to remind them to take a look at the "checklist" for that day. Does that make more sense? Furthermore, I could probably make a "pre-made checklist," but would be unable to go about making the checklist un-check itself at the start of each day.*

Comment: So you understand how to show notifications, but not how to offer the user types of notification?

Comment: Sort of? I didn't know offering a user "types" of notifications was a thing.. I can figure out how to let a user set the time and date of a notification, but I want to have a pre-made notification. So when a user selects plan one, a notification would be set for every week day at 1pm to remind them to take a look at the "checklist" for that day. Does that make more sense? Furthermore, I could probably make a "pre-made checklist," but would be unable to go about making the checklist un-check itself at the start of each day.

Comment: It isn't a thing, you need to make it a thing. Mostly for the local notification you need `repeatInterval`. Each type is just a configuration to create the notification with... You need to try creating your first one and come back with specific issues about each topic.

Comment: Great, I didn't know about `repeatInterval`. That only solves a quarter of my problem, but I found an answer elsewhere that will keep me occupied for now. Thank you!